# Good documentation about securityd,SecurityAgent and loginwindow

Tags: macos, login, authentication

I am looking for good documentation about securityd,SecurityAgent and loginwindow. I am particularly interested in as to how these processes work in unison during Mac OS X login and authenticate the user for both local and network login. Google search does not seem to produce good results. Any links regarding this would be most helpful.

### Thanks in advance.

Ramkumar

Comment: Do you have access to developer.apple.com? If not, register as a OS X developer (it's free) and have a look around.